# How to correct apply :after element to styled components in react.js

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components

i've found this nice underline animation

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

body,html {
  margin: 0;
  font: bold 14px/1.4 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
ul { 
  margin: 150px auto 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none; 
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}
li { 
  display: table-cell; 
  position: relative; 
  padding: 15px 0;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}
a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
}
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    ul {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

I know i have to apply the code above in to my **NavItem** component. Animation and everything is fine but it looks like it's appling in my **NavItem** Component but for whole Navbar
[NavItem CSS and app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHlDG.png)

I'm member just few hours so i dont know what is proper way to show website when its in my localhost. Also sorry for may english. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you work with css.modules and add a className in your component. First create the css module, it is simple. Follow this steps:

- **Create a css file in the same past of your component: name.module.css,  create a logic for your css**
- **Import this module for your component:**

```
import classes from './name.module.css';
```

(The name of constant is your choice)

- **Add the className in the tag component:**

```
<NavItem className={classes.nameofclass} />
```

Verify if the class apply the css code for after.